# JavaScript- count how many times button is cliked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to count how many times only 1 specified button is clicked.
In my code I  have 8 buttons and in p element is shown the number every time I click any other button.

http://prntscr.com/jg26mk

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Separately: Don't post *pictures* of code or other text, post the *text* itself (marked up as code if it's code). More: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: set ids and specific counters for each button, and on click of each button with specific id, increase that particular counter only and display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an ID to the specified button, then in jQuery use `$('#id')` instead of `$('button')`

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are looking for.

```
var count=0;
$(".mySpecialButtons").click(function (){ count++; });
// call this function to show click counts!
function showClicks(){
        alert(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = count++;
}
</script>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kxpbdo4t/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<button type="button" id="SomeID">Countable button</button>
<button type="button" >Unountable button</button>
<button type="button" >Unountable button</button>


<script>
    var count = 0;
    $('body').on('click', '#SomeID', function () {
        count++;
        $("p").text("Number of Count is " + count)
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Ana Kitanovska try this

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate each `button`, create `counter` variable that can only be accessible by the `button` and increment it on click.

```js
$('button').each( function(){
  var counter = 0;
  
  $( this ).click( function(){
    counter++;
    alert( this.innerText + ' has been clicked ' + counter + ' times' );
  } );
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button A</button>
<button>Button B</button>
<button>Button C</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your special button an `id` and use it on `click` event. Like this:

```js
var count = 0;
$("button#special").on('click', function() {
  count ++;
  $("p").text(count);
});

$("p").text(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Send</button>
<button id="special">Click Me to count</button>
<br />
<button>Send</button>
<button>Click</button>
<br />
<button>Send</button>
<button>Click</button>
<br />
<button>Send</button>
<button>Click</button>
<br />
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

A closure should do the trick, as described in [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-closures#module-usecaseeventhandlers) article. So, there is no need to define a global variable to count clicks and pollute the global namespace.

```
element.onclick = (function outer() {
    let counter = 0;
    return function inner() {
        counter++;
        console.log('ID:' + element.id + 'Number of clicks: ' + counter);
    };
})();
```

The `counter` variable will be unique for every button, so you will have information for each button how many times it was clicked.